# changed root UID in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, root, file-recovery, uid

I was tinkering with the /etc/passwd file when accidentaly changed the root UID and GID.
When I enter into the recovery mode, I still have no superuser powers, as any user exists on the passwd file with UID and GID 0.
I read something about booting the pc from a live cd and mounting a partition, but I don't fully understand what does this mean.
Maybe you can give me a solution and a link to a tutorial or just explain it here step by step.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit like this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

You boot Linux from the *Live CD* (not using it as a replacement boot loader, but booting into the *Live CD* installation).

Then mount the partition containing `/` of your hard disk installation, similar to the tutorial.

Stop before doing `chroot`! Just `cd` the the directory where you mounted it, enter `etc`, `cp passwd passwd.backup` for good measure (in case your cat jumps on the keyboard one moment later) and `vi passwd`.